# reactjs ag-grid headerCheckboxSelection select all rows by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

In my column definition, I use headerCheckboxSelection = true, which is good and have checkbox on the header that toggles all rows selected or not.

How do I make the header checkbox selected by default?

```
{
    colId: "groupSelection",
    headerName: "Name",
    minWidth: 40,
    maxWidth: 40,
    resizable: false,
    type: "group",
    checkboxSelection: true,
    headerCheckboxSelection: true,
},
```

I can't seem to find the right property to set this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over each row node and select via api:

```
<AgGridReact
  ...
  onFirstDataRendered={({api}) => api.forEachNode(node => node.setSelected(true))}
/>
```